# Python VLC Running pause() twice does not resume playing?

Tags: python, vlc

```
import vlc,os,time,multiprocessing
from threading import Thread

def play_single(filePath):
    item = Player(filePath)
    Thread(target=item.startProcessing).start()
    Thread(target=item.asyncInput).start()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.media = vlc.Media(file)
        self.skip = False

    def asyncInput(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            if command == "-skip" or command == "-quit":
                self.skip = True
                break
            elif command == "-pause" or command == "-resume":
                self.player.pause()
            else:
                print("else")

    def startProcessing(self):
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        self.player.play()
        time.sleep(2)
        while True:
            if (self.player.is_playing() == 0):
                self.player.stop()
                break
            if self.skip:
                self.player.stop()
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_single("C:/Users/Satvik/Music/Dua Lipa - Levitating.mp3")
```

When i execute `-pause` it pauses but when I execute `-resume` it does not have any effect. Please help I can't figure out why it is doing that. This above is my whole code every other thing works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you execute 'self.player.pause()' for both  pause and resume

change this

```
elif command == "-pause" or command == "-resume":
```

to

```
if command == "-pause":
                self.player.pause()
elif command == "-resume":
                self.player.play()
```

Comment: I's using VLC and self.player has not resume() method. It uses same method pause() to toggle pause.

Comment: It does have a `play` method though.

Comment: @SatvikVirmani I haven't used vlc module before so as Paul M. pointed out, it uses play() for resuming also, use that instead. I also updated the answer. Please accept it if it solves your problem. Thanks!!

Comment: When I use `play()` and execute resume for first time it does not resume but instead replays the entire song. But if I execute `resume()` the second time and after that it resumes it (i.e it works).

Comment: @SatvikVirmani remove this block of code: `if (self.player.is_playing() == 0): self.player.stop() break`

Comment: @SEKTION Thanks it worked. Really Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'toggle play pause' command unlike for mute, `audio_toggle_mute`.

You can implement it yourself though, by checking the status of the mediaplayer.

```py
def toggle_(self):
        if self.player.is_playing():
            self.player.pause()
        else:
            self.player.play()
```

Comment: This is the correct way to address this problem. Or check media `state` for 3 or 4 but this is easier and more readable.